# How to: If data attribute equals radio select add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I'm having an issue figuring out how to code this, I'm new to JS/jQuery so go easy on me!

I want to get the id of what radio button is selected, which I have accomplished. I then want to find a table row `<tr>` that has a matching data attribute and add a class to it. My issue is trying to find the value of the data attribute cause the TR comes back undefined since there's multiple data attributes, so I can't do:

```
if (dataAttribute = radioSelect) {
    $(this).addClass("test");
}
```

Basically my issue is with the multiple table rows and not knowing how to single them out.

Here's a rough example of my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/2dsvrhjo/1/

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `if (dataAttribute = radioSelect)` does not compare `dataAttribute` to `radioSelect`

Comment: @guest271314 I know, that little snippet of code does nothing, was just an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Wasn't sure how else to describe what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can use attribute value equals selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select by data-attributes like so:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
    // Get Choice for Application
    var application = $('input[name="application"]:checked').prop('id') || '';
  
    // Get all tr's with the selected data-app
    var $trs = $('tr[data-app="'+application+'"]');
  
    // Add your class
    $trs.addClass('highlight');
  
    // Remove the class from all other tr's
    $('tr').not($trs).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="Aviation" name="application" />Aviation<br>
  <input type="radio" id="Civil" name="application" />Civil
</div>
<table border="1" style="text-align:center;">
  <tr>
    <th>Section One</th>
    <th>Section Two</th>
  </tr>
   <tr data-app="Aviation">
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-app="Civil">
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-app="Aviation">
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-app="Civil">
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple case:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function () {
        // Get Choice for Application
    var application = $(this).attr('id');
  $('table').find('tr').each(function(i){
      if ($(this).attr('data-app') == application){
        $(this).addClass('test');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('test');
      }

  });
});
```

Just update your fiddle with code above.

That code is looping thorough each  and checking for matching 'data-app'

Comment: This will only work correctly for the first time something is selected. When the value changes, the class is not removed from the previous tr's.

Comment: It just very simple example. I know it should be else statement for removing class. See update above.